# Not able to complete meta box save function and sanitization/validation

Tags: plugins, metabox

Before Coming to this Point I have consulted various times →

1. [Validation Function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275144/validation-function-for-url-in-plugin)
2. [On StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391188/url-analogue-of-files)

Consulted other existing articles Here:

## 1 [WS1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115602/how-do-i-display-youtube-vimeo-video-id-on-custom-post-type-when-user-enters-it)

## 2 [WS2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119377/custom-meta-field-youtube-embed)

Finally,

I came up with my version →

```
    function cpmb_add_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cpmb-admin', plugins_url( 'b-cpt/css/admin.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cpmb_add_admin_styles' );



function cpmb_add_admin_scripts() {

     /*Get the current screen*/
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // Compare the current screen's ID with 'post'. If they are equal, enqueue the JavaScript
    if( 'post' == $screen->id ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cpmb-admin', plugins_url( 'b-cpt/js/admin.js' ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cpmb_add_admin_scripts' );




function cpmb_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'cpmb_video',             // The ID for the meta box
        'Add Video URL',          // The title of the meta box
        'cpmb_display_meta_box',  // The function for rendering the markup
        'post',                   // We'll only be displaying this on post pages
        'advanced',               // Where the meta box should appear
        'high'                    // The priority of where the meta box should be displayed
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cpmb_add_meta_box' );




function cpmb_display_meta_box( $post ) {

    // Define the nonce for security purposes
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'cpmb-nonce-field' );

    // Start the HTML string so that all other strings can be concatenated
    $html = '';


    // Display the 'MP3 File' label and its file input element
    $html .= '<label id="video-url" for="video-url">';
        $html .= 'Video URL';
    $html .= '</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="URL" id="video-url" name="video-url" value="" />';



    $video_type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_video_type',true);
    $video_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_text',true);


    $html . = '<p>'
    $html . = '<label for="my_meta_box_text">Select video type:</label>'
         <!-- added select for selecting Vedio type -->
    $html . = '<select name="my_video_type" id="my_video_type">  '
    $html . = '<option <?php echo ($video_type == 'youtube') ? "selected='selected'" : "" ;?> value="youtube">Youtube</option>'
    $html . = '<option <?php echo ($video_type == 'vimeo') ? "selected='selected'" : "" ;?> value="vimeo">Vimeo</option>'
    $html . = '</select>'
        <!-- added select for selecting Vedio type -->
    $html . = </p>

    $html . = '<p>'
        $html . = '<label for="my_meta_box_text">Youtube/Vimeo ID:</label>'
        $html . = '<input type="text" name="video-url" id="video-url" value="<?php echo $video_id; ?>" />'
    $html . = '</p>'
    echo $html;



}




function cpmb_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // If the user has permission to save data...
    if ( cpmb_user_can_save( $post_id, 'cpmb-nonce-field' ) ) {

        // ...and if the MP3 file is setup, then check to make sure its valid and save it, as well
        if ( isset( $_POST['video-url'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) {

            if ( url_allowed( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) {

                }

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cpmb_save_meta_box_data' );

function url_allowed( $url ) {
        $allowed_hosts = array(
                        'youtube.com',
                        'vimeo.com'
                        );
        if ( in_array( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ), $allowed_hosts ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

function cpmb_user_can_save( $post_id, $nonce ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce ], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
    return ! ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) && $is_valid_nonce;

}
```

But something is incomplete here in the save function:

```
if ( url_allowed( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) {

                }

        }
```

## Please help me to complete this.

## Please also help me to use wp_kses# etc if they can be applied here.

Please also help me to eliminate any bugs here in this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once validated, you just need to update the post meta with the form input:

```
 if ( url_allowed( $_POST['video-url'] ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'video-url', esc_url( $_POST['video-url'] ) );
 } else {
     //if user edits entry to remove a url from input, it will be deleted
     delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'video-url' );
 }
```

If you look at the source of [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/), you can see it is using  [`wp_allowed_protocols`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allowed_protocols/) and [`wp_kses_normalize_entities()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_normalize_entities/).

---

**Side Note:**

It is also parsing the url with `wp_parse_url()`, a wrapper for php's `parse_url()`, to check the different parts. Not unlike what we did in the `url_allowed()` function (in fact I'll update [that answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/275149/118366) to use `wp_parse_url()` if you want).

Comment: this line is generating error → `$html .= '<option <?php echo ($video_type == 'youtube') ? "selected='selected'" : "" ;?> value="youtube">Youtube</option>';`

Comment: Error → 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'youtube' (T_STRING) in /home2/............../wp-content/plugins/b-cpt/b-metabox.php on line 91`

Comment: that may need to be a separate question, but that first single quote around `'youtube'` is closing the single quote opening that line. something like `'<option '. echo ($video_type == 'youtube') ? "selected='selected'" : "" .' value="youtube">Youtube</option>';` may do it, but there are probably better ways.

Comment: In short remove the php tags? Is that correct?

Comment: I copy pasted your code as you suggested, but the bug is still [there](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/).

Comment: the comment section isn't suited for breaking down what needs to be fixed here. Again, this syntax issue is separate from the question.